# adding array into another array with key value in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter,adding array into another array with key value pairs.

and I have an array in this format

```
Array 
    ( [0] => Array ( 
        [memberName] => Ram
        [address] => Abc 
        [phoneNo] =>456422313
        [email] => abc@abc.com
        [age] => 25 
        )
    )
```

I have to insert this  array into `$data['memberInfo']` with key values.
So when I echo `$memberInfo->memberName` in my view, I could get the correct value of `memberName;`

Comment: do you absolutely need to echo it as an object or is an array ok? if the array is fine, the current answer is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 $data= array('mem_info' => array());
    foreach($val as $key => $value){
           $mem_info= array(
                        array(
                            'memberName' => $value->name,
                            'address' => $value->address, 
                            'phoneNo' => $value->phone',
                            'email' => $value->email,
                            'age' => $value->age
                        )
                    );

            array_push($data['mem_info'], $mem_info[0]);
    }
    var_dump($data['mem_info']);
```

Here $val is another array.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Controller
$data = array(
    'memberInfo' => array()
    // ...
);
$memberInfo = array(
    array(
        'memberName' => 'Ram',
        'address' => 'Abc',
        'phoneNo' => 456422313,
        'email' => 'abc@example.com',
        'age' => 25
    )
);
$data['memberInfo'] = array_merge($data['memberInfo'], $memberInfo[0]);

// View
echo $data['memberInfo']['memberName'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Here i use simple index() method and pass data to view file as an example.

You can use below code and test in your codeigniter.

Hope this will work for you.

> Welcome.php (Controller)

```
public function index(){
    $array = array 
        ( array ( 
            'memberName' => 'Ram',
            'address' => 'Abc', 
            'phoneNo' => '456422313',
            'email' => 'abc@abc.com',
            'age' => 25 
            )
        );

    $data['memberInfo'] = $array[0]; 
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}
```

> welcome_message.php (View)

```
<?php
    echo $memberInfo['memberName'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $memberInfo['address'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $memberInfo['phoneNo'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $memberInfo['email'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $memberInfo['age'];
    echo '<br>';
?>
```

> Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$data['memberInfo'] = $Youarray[0];